# Windows Vista fails to boot BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot, bsod, chkdsk

After fresh reinstall I get an error which says to run CHKDSK on the computer and the error code is 0x0000007B. I didn't even manage to boot it once.
I managed to run checkdisk from vista installation cd (there were some repair options) but it didn't show any errors.

Is the hard drive crashed? I thought that maybe some drivers are missing but I think that it wouldn't let me install OS on it.

Of course I tried to reinstall the system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its not clear if you can you boot into Safe Mode?  You tried to reinstall the operating system?  What happened when you did that?

Comment: 0x0000007B often occurs when you switch the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI. Have you done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem but unfortunately couldn't submit my answer earlier.

I had to switch from AHCI to IDE as someone mentioned in comment - previously there was Vista installed but probably with some drivers and thats why it worked fine.
After change to IDE i had to reinstall system once again.